# RTL text not starting from right when new sentence is started with numbers

Tags: android, textview

I have the following XML -

```kotlin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/group_task_root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/group_task_image"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/group_task_done_indicator"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/done"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/group_task_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textDirection="locale"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="Task's very long title" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

and I for this specific XML I need support for both RTL and LTR.

The issue I am facing looks like this -

[image]

As you can see, I have RTL text that works good, but if I linebreak to a new line and write numbers alone without following RTL text it will be displayed at LTR.

Is there any proper fix for this one?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `android:gravity="right"` into TextView

i hope work for you:)

Comment: What will happen if the text will start with LTR characters?

Comment: You are correct, and this is not what I want to achieve. I want RTL text to start always from right and LTR text to always start from left

Comment: Aha! I have no idea for fixed it by tags attributes. but you can check EditText content.if text is rtl and start paragraph with number you can add '\u200F' at the start of paragraph:)